# C++ How to review and process input with scanf?

Tags: c++, input

I want to process the input so that we know when the input contains a certain character.

For example

```
# Title
Member 1
Member 2
Member 3
# Title 2
Member 1
Member 2
Member 3
etc.
```

How can I know that anything that starts with # is a title, and the lines starting below it until the next # sign are other variables that I can process?

also if the input is

```
title 1 + title 2
```

how can we know that there is a + sign and we want to parse out title 1 and title 2 members?

Comment: Please show your effort. others can chime in. You can use string == operator to compare string equality. open the file in fstream and start reading. You can use string operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know that anything that starts with # is a title

If the 1st char of str (s[0]) is a hash '#':
check the substring that comes next using [substr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) function.

> and the lines starting below it until the next # sign are other variables

Keep working with substr() until you realise that 1st char in line is a hash '#' again.

> how can we know that there is a + sign

You can either iteare string or use [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function, and then split your string for further analysis. To do this, you can either use your self-made explode() function or have some fun playing with substr() function again. Is that clear enough for you?